# I am facing a weird bug in Minecraft stoneblock 2 with Roost

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Whenever I try to make an iron chicken (using a flint and a bone white one), it gives me a flint chicken instead of the iron one that I want. There are pictures included.[image]

Comment: Roost doesn't give you a guaranteed result. There's only a chance that you'll get the right chicken, so just keep trying. You can just cram a bunch of seeds in the feed slot and come back later.

Comment: I don't know this mod at all, but have my upvote, because modded questions always get one or two downvotes. ;) And this seems to actually be a legitimate, on-topic question.

Comment: And it has a picture!

Comment: Are these both 0/0/0 flint and bone chickens?